# How to combine two sql scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for the massively stupid question but I am curious how to get this to work.  Currently I have a query to find a number of records that I need to change based on the months difference between two dates.

```
SELECT [MembershipTermID]
  ,[MemberStatusProgKey]
  ,[StartDate]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[AdditionalDiscount]
  ,[EntryDateTime]
  ,[UpdateDateTime]
  ,[MembershipID]
  ,[AgentID]
  ,[PlanVersionID]
  ,[ForceThroughReference]
  ,[IsForceThrough]
  ,[NextTermPrePaid]
  ,[IsBillingMonthly]
  ,[CICSMEMBERNUM]
  ,[CICSHISTORY]
  ,[TMPSeqNoColumn]
  ,[LastPaymentDate]
  ,[PaidToDate]
  ,[IsIndeterminate]
  ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, PaidToDate, GETDATE()) as MonthsDifference
FROM [Apollo].[dbo].[MembershipTerm] 
WHERE MemberStatusProgKey='DORMANT' AND IsBillingMonthly=1 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, PaidToDate, GETDATE()) > 2
```

However I found this on stackoverflow which is the correct way to pull the exact months difference between two dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FullMonthsSeparation 
(
@DateA DATETIME,
@DateB DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result INT

DECLARE @DateX DATETIME
DECLARE @DateY DATETIME

IF(@DateA < @DateB)
BEGIN
    SET @DateX = @DateA
    SET @DateY = @DateB
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @DateX = @DateB
    SET @DateY = @DateA
END

SET @Result = (
                            SELECT 
                            CASE 
                                    WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @DateX) > DATEPART(DAY, @DateY)
                                    THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, @DateX, @DateY) - 1
                                    ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, @DateX, @DateY)
                            END
                            )

RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

How can I combine them so I'm essentially calculating the full months difference but from the WHERE clause section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're run in your FullmonthsSeperation function to the database, you just need to call it like this:

```
SELECT [MembershipTermID]
  ,[MemberStatusProgKey]
  ,[StartDate]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[AdditionalDiscount]
  ,[EntryDateTime]
  ,[UpdateDateTime]
  ,[MembershipID]
  ,[AgentID]
  ,[PlanVersionID]
  ,[ForceThroughReference]
  ,[IsForceThrough]
  ,[NextTermPrePaid]
  ,[IsBillingMonthly]
  ,[CICSMEMBERNUM]
  ,[CICSHISTORY]
  ,[TMPSeqNoColumn]
  ,[LastPaymentDate]
  ,[PaidToDate]
  ,[IsIndeterminate]
  ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, PaidToDate, GETDATE()) as MonthsDifference
FROM [Apollo].[dbo].[MembershipTerm] 
WHERE MemberStatusProgKey='DORMANT' 
AND IsBillingMonthly=1 
AND dbo.FullMonthsSeparation (PaidToDate, GETDATE()) > 2
```